# Cubesat/Nanosat dispensers/deployers costs

Tags: launch, cubesat, cost, business, nanosatellite

I’ m looking for informations about dispensers/deployers equipement costs and associated launch costs, espacially for 12U configurations and over.
I’ve got price information on Tyvak 12U Deployer in a recent fair, it is about US $96,000.

Does somebody have some information on other 12U dispenser/deployer (e.g. Isis Quadpack, Exolauch Exopod, PSC CSD12U, Utias Xpod, Ruag...) or some examples of the global launch cost for such configuration?

Same question for bigger sat (16U, 27U).

Comment: I'd contact the manufacturers directly and ask them. Did that during the days of my participation in a student CubeSat project and they were quite approachable.

Comment: Thank You. You were lucky! Unfortunatly, only a few spontaneously gave me commercial information for 12U configurations. It's why I'm asking for.

Comment: Unless you are actually planning to buy deployers, most will not give you information.  Competition sensitive and all that.  You could submit a formal request for quote for each, but they will likely want to know why,